# Simple architectural software for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I have tried to find a simple architectural software for Ubuntu. I need something that can draw walls in different materials that has fixtures that can be dropped in to the drawing. A friend lent me Home Designer by Chief Architect. It only works on Windows. Is there a similar, easy to use program for Ubuntu??

Answer (score 4):

[Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp) [image: Install Sweet Home 3D] should do it:

[image: Sweet Home 3D screenshot]

I have used this myself, and I can tell you that it's really nice!